# Paying my visitors to share my pages on social media. Against Google policies? Against Adsense policies?

Tags: seo, google-adsense

Is there is anything wrong with giving incentives to my visitors to share my pages on social media?

Does Google say anything about this practice?

Does Adsense have anything to say about it?

Is it considered as Paid links? If so, then how is this any different from the practice of Taboola and Outbrain?

Comment: I'd be more worried about what the social media sites think about it.   Aren't you worried about having your site banned from being shared on social media altogether?

Answer (score 1):

Google does not say anything about it, nor Adsense.
It is not paid links.

Altough if Google see a incredibly high percentage of shares vs the usual, it might guess you give incentive and ignore totally these shares.
And remember these links are nofollow.